# Swift 4 Add and remove custom cell at index: 0 with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have problem to move cells when i add new cell at indexPath in position 0.
I want to add custom cell at index 0 with animation when click to **Edit** i want to move my pics, it should start from index 1 and when i click **Save**, custom cell should disappear and pics pack to display from index 0 with animation.

**NewAlbumEmptyCollectionViewCell - custom cell**

**EditPhotoCollectionViewCell - default pic cell**
[image]

```
@objc func saveAction(){
        if rightBarButton.title == "Edit"{
            rightBarButton.title = "Save"
            isEditEnabled = true
            UI.collectionView.reloadData()
        }else{
            rightBarButton.title = "Edit"
            isEditEnabled = false
            UI.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

extension NewAlbumViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isEditEnabled == true{
            print(photoAssets.count + 1)
            return photoAssets.count
        }else{
            print(photoAssets.count)
            return photoAssets.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if isEditEnabled == true{
            if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyCell", for: indexPath) as! NewAlbumEmptyCollectionViewCell
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EditPhotoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditPhotoCollectionViewCell

                cell.data = photoAssets[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
        }else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EditPhotoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditPhotoCollectionViewCell
            cell.data = photoAssets[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to return the incremented value for `photoAssets.count + 1`. Do the change as below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isEditEnabled == true{

        print(photoAssets.count + 1)
        return photoAssets.count + 1
    }else{
        print(photoAssets.count)
        return photoAssets.count
    }
}
```

For smooth animation:

```
@objc func saveAction(){
    if rightBarButton.title == "Edit"{
        rightBarButton.title = "Save"
        isEditEnabled = true
        UI.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
    }else{
        rightBarButton.title = "Edit"
        isEditEnabled = false
        UI.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
    }
}
```

Comment: Next thing.. how i can add/remove cell with animation?

Comment: For this instead of reloading collection view just insert or remove the item. I'll update this in my answer.